# Depth First Search in Boost C++ library not showing error

Tags: c++, boost, depth-first-search

```
class MyVisitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor {
public:
    MyVisitor() : vv(new std::vector<DotVertex>()) {}

    void discover_vertex(DotVertex v, const graph_t& g) { //note the lack of const
        //if (boost::in_degree(v, g) != 0) { //only print the vertices in the connected component (I already did MCC and removed edges so all the extra vertices are isolated)
            std::cerr << v.label << std::endl;
            vv->push_back(v);
        //}
        return;
    }
    std::vector<DotVertex>& GetVector() const { return *vv; }
private:
    boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<DotVertex> > vv;
};
```

I wrote the above visitor for DFS in boost. I got the following error:

> error C2664: 'void MyVisitor::discover_vertex(DotVertex,const graph_t
>   &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'unsigned int' to 'DotVertex'

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Provide DotVertex::DotVertex(unsigned int); even if just to find where it's being called.

Comment: The error message comes from a line of code you haven't shown - someplace where you're calling `discover_vertex`.  The line number is part of the error message.  [Edit] the question to include that line of code and the code around it.